# How to create StringVar in a class whose Tk() is defined in some other class?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I need to crate a `DropDown` class & later add it to the `root` or `main` GUI. But `Tkinter.StringVar()` is throwing an error saying

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Testing/Tiks/main2.py", line 64, in <module>
    d = Droppy(application)
  File "D:/Testing/Tiks/main2.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.control_variable = Tkinter.StringVar()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 251, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
Exception AttributeError: "StringVar instance has no attribute '_tk'" in <bound method StringVar.__del__ of <Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x0236F7B0>> ignored`
```

My code is this

```
import Tkinter


class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        ############################
        ############################
        self.root.mainloop()


class Droppy(object):

    def __init__(self, frame=None):
        # if frame is None:
        #     raise Exception
        self.frame = frame
        self.control_variable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.control_variable.set("Choose Options")
        self.dropDown = None

    def dropIt(self):
        self.dropDown = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self.frame.root, self.control_variable, "Rules", "Processing", "Output",
                                           "Actions")
        self.dropDown.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = App()
    # application = Droppy()
    # application.dropIt()
    d = Droppy(application)
    d.dropIt()
```

Now I know that `Tkinter.Tk()` before `Tkinter.StringVar()` can solve this issue but I cannot put `Tkinter.Tk()` and Tkinter.StringVar()` in the same class. How can I avert this issue ? Can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainloop` is endless loop and it is running till you close Tk window.
You create `Droppy` when `App` is already closed.

You have to create object before `mainloop` - for example inside `App.__init__`.

```
import Tkinter


class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        ############################
        d = Droppy(self)
        d.dropIt()
        ############################
        self.root.mainloop()


class Droppy(object):

    def __init__(self, frame=None):
        # if frame is None:
        #     raise Exception
        self.frame = frame
        self.control_variable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.control_variable.set("Choose Options")
        self.dropDown = None

    def dropIt(self):
        self.dropDown = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self.frame.root, self.control_variable, 
                                           "Rules", "Processing", "Output",
                                           "Actions")
        self.dropDown.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = App()
```

Comment: Wow that means I always need to access the main GUI class to add some elements to the Application..Didn't know that..Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can call your mainloop() in the main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = App()
    d = Droppy(application)
    d.dropIt()
    application.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Running the mainloop in the main is not possible..This is a part of some bigger GUI application & all the GUI integration is to be done from the `App` class..However @furas answe seems possible though.Thanks for the answer though